# MongoDB 3.6- How to Append matches from one collection to another?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Collection 1 - Invoice Lines
Collection 2 - Tax Lines

Case: 1 invoice line can have more than one tax line associated to it.

How can I get the 1 invoice line record to have each of its matching tax lines appended to it?

There is a match key between the invoice line and the tax lines.  Right now my aggregation is creating 2 resulting invoice line records (duplicate invoice line with a matching tax line) instead of appending the matching tax lines to the single invoice line record.

[Graphic depiction of current collections and document examples.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF5jF.png)

---

**Invoice Line Sample Document...**

```
{ 
    "UniqueID" : NumberInt(3851963), 
    "InvNum" : NumberInt(35602582), 
    "Location" : "035", 
    "InvoiceDate" : ISODate("2017-07-15T12:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "LINEITEM" : NumberInt(1), 
    "CUSTID" : "001595", 
    "DEPTID" : "035360", 
    "PRODID" : "003600", 
    "ProdDesc" : "MISC MERCHANDISE", 
 }
```

---

**Tax Lines Sample document (need to append both to Invoice Line above)...
Tax Line Document 1**

```
{ 
    "InvoiceDate" : "7/15/2017 12:00:00 AM", 
    "Location" : "035", 
    "InvNum" : NumberInt(35602582), 
    "LineItem" : NumberInt(1), 
    "UniqueID" : NumberInt(1), 
    "taxCode" : "mu48", 
    "taxrate" : NumberInt(2), 
}
```

**Tax Line Document 2**

```
{ 
    "InvoiceDate" : "7/15/2017 12:00:00 AM", 
    "Location" : "035", 
    "InvNum" : NumberInt(35602582), 
    "LineItem" : NumberInt(1), 
    "UniqueID" : NumberInt(1), 
    "taxCode" : "mu48", 
    "taxrate" : NumberInt(2), 
}
```

Comment: Could you show the sample collections

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet does the image pasted in question just now help?

Comment: You have to post sample documents as hain here. Images do not work

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Added them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below [**`aggregation`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wfM5SHv2zke) with mongodb **3.6** and above

```
db.invoice.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "tax",
    "let": { "invNum": "$InvNum", "lINEITEM": "$LINEITEM" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$and": [
            { "$eq": ["$InvNum", "$$invNum"] },
            { "$eq": ["$LineItem", "$$lINEITEM"] }
          ]
        }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "taxes"
  }}
])
```

Comment: the result creates 2 records.  I need each of the 2 tax lines to be part of the single line item.

Comment: I was looking to get 1 record returned that is the line item containing the 2 tax lines within it, not 2 records where each is the tax line with the line item replicated in each of those. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the sample output

Comment: My mistake, your solution works.  Syntax issue on my side.  Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to make the result become objects instead of an array, when I use "$unwind" it separates these into 2 documents instead of remaining as 1 document.  Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

I'm using...

unwind": {
            "path": "$taxes",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
    }

Comment: What should be the key for each  element?

Comment: InvNum and Line Item is ultimately what they all should tied to.  As this is an invoice line, I am trying to associate the 1 or more tax lines that are associated to that invoice line.  So, for example, I buy a "widget" (invoice line) that has (1) local sales tax line and (1) state sales tax line.  I want both of those tax lines on the same document with the invoice line (not as arrays.)

Comment: I think for this you should create a new question with proper explanation. And comment the link here